# Change map language on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, localization

I have Nexus 7. I'll be traveling to Bangkok in a couple of weeks, and would like to change the Google Maps app to display street names in Thai just in case I get lost and need local help, and also for the benefit of the taxi drivers, who may not be familiar with my destinations

Is there a means of switching back and forth the language used on Google Map App?

Comment: On my Google Maps, when you navigate through Bangkok and zoom-in thoroughly, it shows bilingual name (English and Thai). AFAIK, there's no setting to force the language.

Comment: Thanks.  It's just that the zooming in does not show the names in Thai for certain streets.  I print out a copy with of streets near my destinations using full desktop version of Thai google maps.  Thank you again for the response.